# Gson fromJson() with valid Json from OkHttp3 Response not working (closed)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, okhttp

I'm making an android app (obviously Java) and using AsyncTask for OkHttp3 Requests. I want to parse the returned json string into an simple Message object, but it doesn't work.
My response body is as follows:

```
String res_body_str = response.body().string(); // "{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}"
```

When I try to parse this with gson, it fails.
I always get **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2**

Here is some of my code:
My AsyncTask Class

```
protected Message doInBackground(Message...msg) {
    Message res;
    String req_body_str = g.toJson(msg[0]);
    String res_body_str;

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, req_body_str);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute(); //client is static OkHttpClient
        res_body_str = response.body().string(); // "{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}"
    } catch (IOException e) {
        res_body_str = "{\"msg\":\"Connection Failed. Try again later.\"}";
    }
    ////////Everything works to this point
    try {
        res = g.fromJson(res_body_str, Message.class); //ERROR
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res = new Message(res_body_str);
    }
    return res;
}
```

My Message Class

```
public class Message {

    private String msg;

    public Message(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

When i write `res_body_str = "{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}";` before the second try/catch-statement, it works, but not with the response.

**EDIT 1(just to create clarity) :**
The String is `"{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}"` and `res_body_str.charAt(0);` returns `{`

**EDIT 2:**
`System.err.println(res_body_string);` prints `{"msg":"Do it!"}`
`System.err.println(res_body_string.charAt(0));` prints `{`
`System.err.println(res_body_string.charAt(1));` prints `"`
`System.err.println(res_body_string.charAt(2));` prints `m`

**EDIT 3: It works**
I got it working. I had to replace `"` and `\`.

```
res_body_str = response.body().string().replaceAll("\"","");
res_body_str = res_body_str.replaceAll("\\\\","'");
```

Officially the String was `" "{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}" "` but for some reaseon the non-escaped double qoutes weren't got printed. I saw it when i replaced all escaped double-qoutes with nothing.

Comment: Is your server responding `{"msg":"Do it!"}` or `"{"msg":"Do it!"}"`? Those extra quotes at the beggining might cause the error you're facing

Comment: Try adding a default no-args constructor to your Message class.

Comment: My server is responding `'{"msg":Do it!"}'` in python, so in java the double qoutes are getting escaped and the string becomes `"{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}"`; Without those extra qoutes it would be an syntax error

Comment: I've added `public Message() {super();}` to my Message cass, but nothing changed

Comment: Did you try to log/System.out  `res_body_str`?

Comment: `System.err.println(res_body_str);` results in `System.err: "{\"msg\":\"Do it!\"}"`

Comment: A higher level library like retrofit2 might be simpler.

Comment: So does it start with `"` as string or with `{` as object...

Comment: the string is surrounded with qoutes, so the first char (at index 0) is "{"

Comment: if your response already comes as a String can't you just write `String res_body_str = response.body();`?

Comment: no, because ```response.body()``` is type of ResponseBody

Comment: When you log `response.body().string()`, what does it print to the console? Your error seems to indicate something is wrong at the 2nd index (`charAt(1)`) of your string

Comment: `charAt(1);` prints `"`

Comment: Before returning in asynctask please check for starting and ending the string(according to json).If always you have a not completed string , investigate for returning  class type.

Comment: @SelexeR01 can you try with `toString()` instead of `string()`?

Comment: toString() returns the object as String and not the body string